# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Audit job should always have exactly one PolicyPeriod" when we try to start the audit job

Tags: guidewire, gosu

We are facing this exception when we trying to start the Audit Transaction in Guidewire Policy Center. Currently the Audit Transaction is in "Scheduled" Status. We want to move the Audit Transaction "In Progress" but that exception blocking us. Even not able to reproduce the issue in my local system as well as prod-like env.

This issue is raising when two audits are in "Scheduled" Status .

Audit 1 -> Period -> 2022-02-21 to 2023-02-21 - Scheduled Status

Audit 2 -> Period -> 2023-02-21 to 2022-02-21- Scheduled Status

If i am going to start the audit process for Audit1, i m getting the exception

If i am going to start the audit process for Audit2, i m not getting the exception

Even i updated the PolicyPeriod end date time and start date time of Audit1, Even though problem not solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This post is probably rather too brief to attract help. Is there any more technical detail you can add?

Comment: This issue is raising when two audits are in "Scheduled" Status .
Audit 1 -> Period -> 2022-02-21 to 2023-02-21 - Scheduled Status
Audit 2 -> Period -> 2023-02-21 to 2022-02-21- Scheduled Status

If  i am going to start the audit process for Audit1, i m getting the exception

If i am going to start the audit process for Audit2, i m not getting the exception

Even i updated the PolicyPeriod end date time and start date time, Even though not getting any resolution..@halfer

Comment: This issue is raising when two audits are in "Scheduled" Status .
Audit 1 -> Period -> 2022-02-21 to 2023-02-21 - Scheduled Status
Audit 2 -> Period -> 2023-02-21 to 2022-02-21- Scheduled Status

If  i am going to start the audit process for Audit1, i m getting the exception

If i am going to start the audit process for Audit2, i m not getting the exception

Even i updated the PolicyPeriod end date time and start date time, Even though not getting any resolution..@Community

Comment: We tried multiple ways but not able to reproduce the issue in machine

@Community

Comment: is this consistent across all policies in a line of business or all some policies?